# Writing a Hexadecimal Escape Character Sequence using Variables

Tags: javascript

## Testing Hex Character Codes

### Problem

What does a Vertical Tab or a Backspace character actually do? I want to find out.

My experiment is to find out exactly what happens when every hex character is put into a string. I thought the best way to do this would be to created a nested loop to go through each of the 16 hexadecimal characters to create each possible 2 digit hex character code.

I soon discovered that you cannot use the `\x` escape character with interpolated variables, and so I expect what I have set out to do might be impossible.

```
const hexCharacters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
let code = "";
let char1 = "";
let char2 = "";

for (charPos1 = 0; charPos1 < hexCharacters.length; charPos1++) {
  for (charPos2 = 0; charPos2 < hexCharacters.length; charPos2++) {
    char1 = hexCharacters[charPos1];
    char2 = hexCharacters[charPos2];
    code = `${char1}${char2}`;
    printHexChar(code);
  }
}

function printHexChar(string) {
    let output = `<p>Hex Code ${string} = \x${string}</p>`; // THE PROBLEM IS CLEAR
    document.write(output)
}
```

I know it will also probably fail once it gets past 7F or whichever is the last character in the set, but that's not the main issue here! :D

### Potential solution

#### string.prototype.fromCharCode

This sort of string method approach would seem to be the answer, but it is meant for U-16 character codes, and that is not what I wanted to test. There doesn't seem to be an existing string method for hex codes. Probably because nobody would ever want one, but nevertheless it would be cool.

### Conclusion

Is there any way to create an escape character sequence from assembled parts that will render not as plain text, but as a proper escape character sequence?

Apologies if this has been asked before in some form, but with my feeble understanding of things I just couldn't find an answer.

Comment: If you want to output  `\x` literally, then in a string literal you need to escape the escape character, so `\`\\x\``.

Comment: "*`String.fromCharCode` would seem to be the answer, but it is meant for U-16 character codes*" - that's exactly the same character codes that `\x` escape sequences use though - it's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.fromCharCode` with `parseInt`.

```
`<p>Hex Code ${string} = ${String.fromCharCode(parseInt(string, 16))}</p>`;
```

```js
const hexCharacters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
let code = "";
let char1 = "";
let char2 = "";

for (charPos1 = 0; charPos1 < hexCharacters.length; charPos1++) {
  for (charPos2 = 0; charPos2 < hexCharacters.length; charPos2++) {
    char1 = hexCharacters[charPos1];
    char2 = hexCharacters[charPos2];
    code = `${char1}${char2}`;
    printHexChar(code);
  }
}

function printHexChar(string) {
    let output = `<p>Hex Code ${string} = ${String.fromCharCode(parseInt(string, 16))}</p>`;
    document.write(output)
}
```

`eval` works as well, though it should generally be avoided.

```
`<p>Hex Code ${string} = ${eval('"\\x'+string+'"')}</p>`
```

Comment: @HotSauceCoconuts It's not necessary here and it can be unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output `\x` literally, then in a string literal you need to escape the escape character, so `` `\\x` ``.

> string.prototype.fromCharCode [...] is meant for U-16 character codes

JavaScript uses one character encoding. The following strings are all equal:

```js
let a = String.fromCharCode(27);
let b = "\x1B";
let c = "\u001B";

console.log(a === b, b === c);
```

If I understand correctly, you want to produce a string literal that shows  `\x` escape sequences -- not the actual character:

```js
// Prepare string
let chars = Array.from({length: 128}, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(i))
                 .join("");

// Escape them
let escaped = Array.from(chars, ch => `\\x${ch.charCodeAt().toString(16).padStart(2, "0")}`).join("");

console.log(escaped);
```

But you might also use `JSON.stringify`. Although it uses different escape sequences (`\u` instead of `\x`), and only for non-display characters, it will be the exact same string when evaluated. Here is a demo:

```js
// Prepare string
let chars = Array.from({length: 128}, (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(i))
                 .join("");

// Escape them
let escaped = '"' + Array.from(chars, ch => `\\x${ch.charCodeAt().toString(16).padStart(2, "0")}`).join("") + '"';

console.log(escaped);

// Or JSONify them
let json = JSON.stringify(chars);
console.log(json);

// Compare them, when evaluated:
console.log(eval(escaped) === eval(json));
```

Finally, note that there is nothing special about hexadecimal: it is just a *representation* of an integer. In the end, it is the numerical *value* that is important, not the representation of it. It is that numerical value that corresponds to a character.

### Addendum

If you prefer code that sticks to old-style JavaScript, here is something equivalent of the last code snippet:

```js
// Prepare string
let chars = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    chars += String.fromCharCode(i);
}

// Escape the characters in this string
let escaped = '"';
for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    let ch = chars.charCodeAt(i);
    let hex = ch.toString(16);
    if (hex.length === 1) hex = "0" + hex;
    escaped += "\\x" + hex;
}
escaped += '"';
console.log(escaped);

// Or JSONify them
let json = JSON.stringify(chars);
console.log(json);

// Compare them, when evaluated:
console.log(eval(escaped) === eval(json));
```

Comment: "Finally, note that there is nothing special about hexadecimal: it is just a representation of an integer." Thank you this is something I was unclear on!

Comment: There is a lot here that is completely foreign to me :( How might I go about breaking these expressions down to study them?

Comment: Added some equivalent code in old-style JavaScript.